# How encode strings using python

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, encode, mojibake

I have lists with element

```
[u'\xd0\xbc\xd1\x82\xd1\x81 \xd0\xbe\xd1\x84\xd0\xb8\xd1\x86\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb9 \xd1\x81\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd1\x82']
[u'\xd0\xbc\xd1\x82\xd1\x81 \xd0\xbe\xd1\x84\xd0\xb8\xd1\x86\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb9 \xd1\x81\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd1\x82']
```

I try to convert it using

```
val[0].encode('utf-8')
```

And got after it

```
Ð¼ÑÑ Ð¾ÑÐ¸ÑÐ¸Ð°Ð»ÑÐ½ÑÐ¹ ÑÐ°Ð¹Ñ
Ð¼ÑÑ Ð¾ÑÐ¸ÑÐ¸Ð°Ð»ÑÐ½ÑÐ¹ ÑÐ°Ð¹Ñ
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Do those lists contain UTF-8 bytes?  If so, how/why are they stored in `unicode` objects?

Comment: @SLaks, I write it in my question. Usually I use `encode('utf-8')`, and I try `val[0].decode('latin1').decode('cp1251')`, but it doesn't help in my problem

Comment: @jwodder, I took url like `https://yandex.ru/touchsearch?clid=1906591&text=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%20%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%20-%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%BE%202012&lr=213&redircnt=1465849826.1` and next `get2 = urlparse(url)
            dict2 = parse_qs(get2[4])
            val = dict2['text']`, I get search request from url and I want to decode that

Comment: `dict2['text']` gives you the byte string `'\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd1\x87...'`, not a Unicode string as above. To turn that into `u'\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd1\x87...'` you must have decoded using a Latin-1 encoding (ISO-8859-1 or Windows code page 1252), instead of UTF-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake); text decoded using the wrong codec.

You have what looks like it was decoded or Latin-1 or Windows codepage 1252, while it should have been decoded as UTF-8 instead.

Either reverse the encoding manually, or use the excellent [`ftfy` package](https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to do it for you:

```
>>> import ftfy
>>> data = [u'\xd0\xbc\xd1\x82\xd1\x81 \xd0\xbe\xd1\x84\xd0\xb8\xd1\x86\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb9 \xd1\x81\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd1\x82']
>>> ftfy.ftfy(data[0])
u'\u043c\u0442\u0441 \u043e\u0444\u0438\u0446\u0438\u0430\u043b\u044c\u043d\u044b\u0439 \u0441\u0430\u0439\u0442'
>>> print ftfy.ftfy(data[0])
мтс официальный сайт
```

Manually, you'd re-encode as Latin-1:

```
>>> data[0].encode('latin1')
'\xd0\xbc\xd1\x82\xd1\x81 \xd0\xbe\xd1\x84\xd0\xb8\xd1\x86\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb9 \xd1\x81\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd1\x82'
>>> data[0].encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
u'\u043c\u0442\u0441 \u043e\u0444\u0438\u0446\u0438\u0430\u043b\u044c\u043d\u044b\u0439 \u0441\u0430\u0439\u0442'
>>> print data[0].encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
мтс официальный сайт
```

Note that you have a list with one `unicode` object in it. You may want to study up on Python and Unicode; I recommend the following documents:

- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder
- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)

These will help you understand when to encode and when to decode, and what codec to use.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation!